# input() function: why does prompt line is displayed after user input line?

Tags: python

I'm using a modification of `sys.stdout` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python/5916874#5916874) so to be able to capture warning messages and store them in a variable during execution:

```
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.warnings = []

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        if "WARNING" in message:
            self.warnings.append(message)
    
    def flush(self):
        pass

sys.stdout = Logger()

user_input = input("Your input: ")
print("Your input is: "+user_input)
```

It has the unwanted effect of displaying the prompt line after the user input line when using `input()` function (i.e. in my example above the user must enter its input even before the message `"Your input: "` is displayed). How can I solve this, ideally with a small modification of the `Logger` class ?

Python version: 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes down to your flush method. Here's the simplest change I could make to your code to achieve your desired result:

```
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.warnings = []
        
    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        if "WARNING" in message:
            self.warnings.append(message)

    def flush(self):
        self.terminal.flush()
        
sys.stdout = Logger()

user_input = input("Enter your input: ")
print("Now I will print your input: "+user_input)
```

Note that if you were to write to a log file as well as the terminal (one of the main potential benefits of using a Logger class like this), you'd need to flush your log file in `flush()` as well. See below for an example.

```
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, log_file):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log_file = log_file
        
        self.warnings = []
        
    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log_file.write(message)

        
        if "WARNING" in message:
            self.warnings.append(message)

    def flush(self):
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.log_file.flush()
        

def main():
    file_path = 'log.txt'
    sys.stdout = Logger(open(file_path, 'w'))

    user_input = input("Enter your input: ")
    print("Now I will print your input: "+user_input)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It solves my issue in a simple way :)